# How do I add a POJO to a list using Spring/Thymeleaf form?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a very simply object called Move:

```
public class Move {

private String move;

public String getMove() {
    return move;
}

public void setMove(String move) {
    this.move = move;
}
}
```

I also have a move repository(list of all moves):

```
@Component
public class MoveRepository {

private List<Move>allMoves;

public void addMove(Move move){
    allMoves.add(move);
}

public MoveRepository() {
    this.allMoves = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setAllMoves(List<Move> allMoves) {
    this.allMoves = allMoves;
}

public List<Move> getAllMoves(){
    return allMoves;
}

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MoveController {

@Autowired
private MoveRepository moveRepository = new MoveRepository();

@GetMapping("/moveList")
public String listMoves (ModelMap modelMap){
    List<Move> allMoves = moveRepository.getAllMoves();
    modelMap.put("moves", allMoves);
    return "moveList";
}

@GetMapping("/addMove")
public String addMoveForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("move", new Move());
    return "addMove";
}

@PostMapping("/addMove")
public String addMoveSubmit(@ModelAttribute Move move) {
    moveRepository.addMove(move); //Producing an error
    return "moveAdded";
}

}
```

Basically, I want to add the move submitted using the form on the webpage "/addMove" to the list of moves allMoves in the Move Repository. However, it produces a 500 server error whenever I click the submit button on the webpage. If I delete the

```
  moveRepository.addMove(move);
```

from my code then everything works fine, but then of course the move does not get added to the move repository.

I also have my html(using thymeleaf) code posted below for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Add Move</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Add a move</h1>
<form action = "#" th:action="@{/addMove}" th:object="${move}" method = "post">
<p>Move: <input type = "text" th:field="*{move}"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works for me with your code. Please, can you add the console output?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Change

```
@Autowired
private MoveRepository moveRepository = new MoveRepository();
```

to

```
@Autowired
private MoveRepository moveRepository;
```

The idea is that Spring should handle instantiation of objects through dependency injection.  Also, make sure that your annotations are picked up with component scanning (either in your XML or Java config).

Other tips:

- It isn't so helpful to have the property named `move` in a class of
  the same name.  More descriptive naming would be much better for the
  next person reading your code.
- If your team allows it, try [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to
  get rid of the boilerplate code.  Then you can just do:

  ```
  public class Move {

     @Getter
     @Setter
     private String move;

  }
  ```

  or even better:

  ```
  @Data
  public class Move {

     private String move;

  }
  ```
- Consider annotating your repository with `@Repository` if you're planning to persist to a database.  This will also give you some exception handling features through Spring.